# Efficient way to find n most frequent words per category on text data

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, countvectorizer

I'm trying to optimize below calculation because without subsetting it's hard to calculate it on normal laptop (because of RAM) and this is just example of actual problem. I need directions how to speed it up a lot.

I believe that I need to make use of sparse matrixes as this is typical problem but I'm not sure how to approach it without pandas. OR maybe there is a helper library which is optimized to do things like this.

If not I'm thinking of using dask to calculate some of the calculations in parallel.

Example data:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
import pandas as pd
import random

data = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')
data = pd.DataFrame({'text': data.data[:1000]})

CAT1 = [f'cat1_{i}' for i in range(3)]
CAT2 = [f'cat2_{i}' for i in range(10)]

data['cat1'] = [random.choice(CAT1) for _ in range(data.shape[0])]
data['cat2'] = [random.choice(CAT2) for _ in range(data.shape[0])]
data
```

[image]

My calculation:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3), min_df=5, max_df=1.0)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data['text'])
topwords = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(data[['cat1', 'cat2']]))
topwords.columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
topwords = topwords.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['cat1', 'cat2'],
                                                 var_name='WORDS',
                                                 value_name='Value')
topwords = topwords.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2', 'WORDS'])['Value'].sum().reset_index()
topwords = topwords.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2']).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(10, 'Value'))
topwords.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

[image]

**[EDIT]**: This is the best I could to. I solved problem of RAM. But it's still too slow because of that group by on dictionaries. I wonder how could I do it better.

```
from collections import Counter
data['text_count'] = data['text'].apply(lambda row: Counter(row.split())) # Wall time: 1.22 s
data = data.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2'])['text_count'].sum().reset_index() # Wall time: 2min 5s
data['top_words'] = data['text_count'].apply(lambda row: row.most_common(3)) # Wall time: 203 ms
data = data.explode('top_words') # Wall time: 4 ms
data = pd.DataFrame(data['top_words'].tolist(), 
                    columns= ['WORDS', 'Value'],  
                    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(data[['cat1', 'cat2']])).reset_index() # Wall time: 27.5 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is certainly naive method of approaching any data in data science. I personally work on embeddings for question answering based on FAISS / Elastic search indexing. The beauty of FAISS (Facebook AI Similarity Search) is that, it vectorizes entire corpus data first into an n dimensional space(n= # of features). One can perform many querying operations

[Faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) is a library for efficient similarity search and clustering of dense vectors. It contains algorithms that search in sets of vectors of any size, up to ones that possibly do not fit in RAM. It also contains supporting code for evaluation and parameter tuning. Faiss is written in C++ with complete wrappers for Python/numpy. Some of the most useful algorithms are implemented on the GPU. It is developed by Facebook AI Research.

Faiss contains several methods for similarity search. It assumes that the instances are represented as vectors and are identified by an integer, and that the vectors can be compared with L2 (Euclidean) distances or dot products or any other type of similarity metric. Vectors that are similar to a query vector are those that have the lowest L2 distance or the highest dot product with the query vector. It also supports cosine similarity, since this is a dot product on normalized vectors.

Often times, querying is faster because it is based on hash maps (dictionaries in python). Therefore, if we need a value, we just need to remember it's key & traversal operation is a constant time operation O(1) than O(n*n) with pandas where we have to run through n rows & n columns. Also check out [elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/) if you are working on a big database of text. Elastic search is still the SOTA in information extraction and is core concept behind search engines.

I hope this helps your problem.

Answer (score 0):

So this is MY fastest way of doing it with little resources to use:

```
from collections import Counter    
data = data.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2'])['text'].sum().reset_index() # Wall time: 15.4 ms
data['text_count'] = data['text'].apply(lambda row: Counter(row.split())) # Wall time: 53.3 ms
data['top_words'] = data['text_count'].apply(lambda row: row.most_common(3)) # Wall time: 15.6 ms
data = data.explode('top_words') # Wall time: 0 ns
data = pd.DataFrame(data['top_words'].tolist(), 
                    columns= ['WORDS', 'Value'],  
                    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(data[['cat1', 'cat2']])).reset_index() # Wall time: 0 ms
```

But maybe someone has a more elegant way of doing it.